# If-Then-Else-EndIf VERSUS IIF

Tags: vba, if-statement

I would like know why these following code aren't equals :

```
test = IIf(CURRENCY_ Is Nothing, " ", IIf(IsEmpty(CURRENCY_.Value), " ", CStr(CURRENCY_.Value)))
```

and

```
If CURRENCY_ Is Nothing Then
     test = " "
Else: IsEmpty (CURRENCY_.Value)
     test = CStr(CURRENCY_.Value)
End If
```

For the first code I obtain the error below:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

Someone can help me?

Comment: Note: `Else: IsEmpty (CURRENCY_.Value)` - shouldn't that be `ElseIf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IIF()` evaluates both the true and the false part, before giving the result. Thus, if the `False` part gives some kind of error, the error would be thrown:

```
Sub TestMeIIf()        
    Debug.Print IIf(True, "It is true", 0 / 0)        
End Sub
```

- [IIF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function)

The `If()-Else-End If` evaluates only the `True` part. If the `False` part throws error, it would be ignored:

```
Sub TestMeIf()
    If True Then
        Debug.Print "It is true!"
    Else
        Debug.Print 0 / 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Good edit on changing wording from "compile" to "evaluate" :)

Comment: @BigBen - I knew it was the false term, but I was not sure which one it was. The documentation helped :)